# Persistence in a database

Tags: c#, persistence

I have two lists and one list box, The lists are each their own Class and the listbox is on the Form1.  Each list is added to by a GUI with the respective name, FrmPickups for the pickups list and FrmVisits for the list.

My question is how can I when I add the data to a list, also store it to a database to be reloaded when the project is started up, And how can I load it on start up into the list box.

Some code follows:

Data is added to the list as follows:

```
        theVisit.name = txtName.Text;
        theVisit.address = txtAddress.Text;
        theVisit.arrival = DateTime.Parse(txtArrival.Text);
        theVisit.Lat = Double.Parse(txtLat.Text);
        theVisit.Lon1 = Double.Parse(txtLong.Text);
        theVisit.type = "Visit";
```

ListBox contents are added in the following

```
 /*
         * Update the list on this form the reflect the visits in the list
         */
        lstVisits.Items.Clear();
        //Clear all the existing visits from the list

        List<String> listOfVis = theList.listVisits();
        //Get a list of strings to display in the list box

        List<String> listOfpic = thePickup.listPickups();
        //Get a list of strings to display in the list box

        lstVisits.Items.AddRange(listOfVis.ToArray());
        //Add the strings to the listBox. Note to add a list of strings in one go we have to 
        //use AddRange and we have to use the ToArray() method of the list that we are adding

        lstVisits.Items.AddRange(listOfpic.ToArray());
        //Add the strings to the listBox. Note to add a list of strings in one go we have to 
        //use AddRange and we have to use the ToArray() method of the list that we are adding
```

Comment: what does your data access layer look like?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't even know what that is..., This is the exact reason I applied for first year uni but meh, I am a total noobie

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

As with most programming problems, there are a million ways to do this.  If you have control over the database design, you might consider having a blob or image column in which to store your list.  You can take advantage of serialization in C# and stuff the raw bytes into that column.  This would make querying for details of the list impossible from a sql query point of view.
In regards to loading at startup, you'd grab the raw bytes from the column, deserialize them and attache them to the control of your form.